# Google Cloud Build's GitHub Integration is broken

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

If you follow the setup over at GitHub Marketplace https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build, you will get to a screen in Google Cloud that ask you to select repos to work with Google Cloud Build. The problem is that only the 30 repos are pulled from Google Cloud and no more repos can be setup.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue. Work for a GCP Consulting firm. Have been talking with Google for the last few days. They are aware of the issue and working on a bug fix. Google gave me a time to resolution of next Wednesday.

[Google Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR68m.png)